# what ports are used for files transfer in the lan?

Tags: networking

when I'm using Ethernet LAN....many things you can do on the LAN, one of them is to transfer files between computers after sharing the files.....the question is :
what ports are used for files transfer in the LAN and what the services are used by windows to do this process?
I tried to search in windows server role services at this link (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc875824.aspx)! . I can't find the related services or port

Comment: Typically a file-share in a Windows environment uses [SMB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block)

Answer (score 1):

The [Server Message Block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) (SMB) protocol is used by Windows clients and servers for their native file and printer sharing functionality. (Obviously, there are other protocols, too, but "traditional" Windows file and printer sharing uses SMB).

Versions of Windows prior to Windows 2000 encapsulate SMB in the NetBIOS over TCP (NBT) protocol, which uses TCP port 139. Windows 2000 introduced SMB directly over TCP, which uses TCP port 445.

The SMB client in implemented as a function of the "Workstation" service (also called the `LanManWorkstation` service, showing the protocol's heritage going back to the old Microsoft LAN Manager product). The SMB server is implemented as a function of the "Server" service (`LanManServer`).

These services are installed by default on all versions of Windows in the Windows NT family when networking is present (yes, yes-- it is technically possible to install Windows NT 4.0 and prior versions w/o these services, but that presumes you haven't installed any network adapter, too). Even versions of Windows that have "Roles and Features" install these services by default.